# PHP Filter html select option value if it is found in the database

Tags: php, html, arrays, filter, html-select

I have a database where plots (spots/places) are saved (this can be 5, 40 ,91 etc. (not incremented))
On my website I have a dropdown option where available plots are selected (0 - 1023).
I want the option that is found in the database to be hidden from the dropdown selection on the website.
So if plot 1 is taken it is found in the database and it shouldn't be available in the website dropdown selection. I can't seem to get this working...

This is the code that I came up with.

```
<label for="plotnumber">Plotnumber :</label></br>
<select name="input_plotnumber">

<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 1023; $i++) : ?>

$query = ("SELECT plotnumber FROM plot1");
$result = $conn->query($query);
$arrayofplots = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

if (in_array($i, $arrayofplots)) {

}
else {
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
}

<?php endfor; ?>?>
</select>
```

Comment: Making the exact same database query over a thousand times, that is really bad. At least put that part _before_ the loop. And `mysqli_fetch_all` does not give you a “flat” array containing _only_ the numbers, so you will have to create that first, if you want in_array to work.

Comment: How do you signify, in the database table, that a particular plot is `taken`? Do you set a 1/0 in a particular column for instance?

Comment: You also seem to have some of the PHP code outside of a PHP block, which will just output it as text instead of being executed. Also, just saying _"I cant seem to get this working"_ is a terrible explanation. You should always explain (in detail) what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes I have a collum with the option taken or not taken.
thank you

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I see! ok will fix that! 
Thank you too!

Comment: _“I have a collum with the option taken or not taken”_ - then add a WHERE clause to your query, to make it return the IDs of the taken plots only. The rest are of no interest to what you attempt to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to convert the two-dimensional array returned by `mysqli_fetch_all` into a one-dimensional array before you can use `in_array`.
- As you have some column to indicate if the plot is taken, you need to put that in a `WHERE` clause. I have used `taken=1` but if you have a string like `taken/not taken` then modify it accordingly.
- Avoid running a query in a loop. Instead you should fetch the data at the top.
- As a rule of thumb, choose either the object oriented style `$result->fetch_all()` or procedural `mysqi_fetch_all()`, instead of mixing both.

Updated code:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT plotnumber FROM plot1 WHERE taken=1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$arrayofplots = $result->fetch_all();

// convert to a 1d array
$arrayofplots = array_map(function($row){
  return $row[0];
}, $arrayofplots);

?>

<label for="plotnumber">Plotnumber :</label></br>
<select name="input_plotnumber">

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1023; $i++){
  if (!in_array($i, $arrayofplots)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
  }
}
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the SQL to select all taken plots you can then decide to only output `option` elements whose value is not within that recordset. Based upon your comment that there is a column `taken` you might try like this:

```
<label>Plotnumber :

    <br />

    <?php
        $sql='select plotnumber from plot1 where taken=1';
        $res=$conn->query($sql);
        $data=$res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    ?>


    <select name="input_plotnumber">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select Plot
        <?php
            for( $i=0; $i < 1024; $i++ ){
                if( !in_array( $i, array_column($data,'plotnumber') ) )printf('<option>%d',$i);
            }
        ?>
    </select>

</label>
```